# How to print a dictionary in tabular form and alphabetically?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4, tabular

I have a dictionary and wish to print in tabular form with the first header as "code" and second as "name" and then sorted alphabetically.

i have currently:

```
 import json
 q = my_dict() #which is the dictionary
 d = json.dumps(q)
 print(d)
```

output:

```
"GEL": "Georgian Lari",
"BOB": "Bolivian Boliviano",
"ZAR": "South African Rand",
```

Which is the wrong way round and i am not sure how to insert columns titles. Sorting by Alphabetical order would also help me a lot!

```
Name                   Code
"Bolivian Boliviano"   "BOB"
"Georgian Lari"        "GEL"
"South African Rand"   "Zar"
```

Something like this is what im looking for.

Comment: ...huh? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. What's your *expected* output?

Comment: Expected output added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need the quotes, but you can print your dictionary in the order you want with:

```
max_len = max([len(v) for v in d.values()])
padding = 4
for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i:i[1]):
    print('{v:{v_len:d}s} {k:3s}'.format(v_len=max_len+padding,
                                           v=v, k=k))
```

Output:

```
Bolivian Boliviano     BOB
Georgian Lari          GEL
South African Rand     ZAR
```

The `key` argument to `sorted` ensures that the dictionary's items are sorted by value.

EDIT: as requested, make the field length match the dictionary value length (plus some padding).

Comment: I'd ADORE this answer if you had some code that checked for sane values for the length of each string formatting field, rather than just hardcoding it. If one of my first column values is `"Holy Crap This Is A Long Value"`, it shouldn't break the tabulation.

Answer (score 9):

If third-party modules are an option, you can use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

Run this from the command line:

```
$ pip install tabulate
```

Then in your script

```
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ['Name', 'Code']
data = sorted([(v,k) for k,v in d.items()]) # flip the code and name and sort
print(tabulate(data, headers=headers))
```

That will give you the output

```
Name                Code
------------------  ------
Bolivian Boliviano  BOB
Georgian Lari       GEL
South African Rand  ZAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(d)
```